# Event listener fails to attach or remove in some contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, web-applications, event-handling

I've created a script that attaches an event listener to a collection of pictures by default. When the elements are clicked, the listener swaps out for another event that changes the image source and pushes the id of the element to an array, and that reverses if you click on the swapped image (the source changes back and the last element in the array is removed). There is a button to "clear" all of the images by setting the default source and resetting the event listener, but it doesn't fire reliably and sometimes fires with a delay, causing only the last element in a series to be collected.

TL;DR: An event fires very unreliably for no discernible reason, and I'd love to know why this is happening and how I should fix it. The JSFiddle and published version are available below.

I've uploaded the current version [here](http://heptane.smgx.co/LickyLickySakeSake), and you can trip the error by selecting multiple tables, pressing "Cancel", and selecting those buttons again. Normally the error starts on the second or third pass.

I've also got a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj0jjkLw/7/).

The layout will be a bit wacky on desktops and laptops since it was designed for phone screens, but you'll be able to see the issue and inspect the code so that shouldn't be a problem.

**Code blocks:**

Unset all the selected tables:

```
    function tableClear() {

        //alert(document.getElementsByClassName('eatPlace')[tableResEnum].src);
        //numResTables = document.getElementsByClassName('eatPlace').src.length;

        tableArrayLength = tableArray.length - 1;

        for (tableResEnum = 0; tableResEnum <= tableArrayLength; tableResEnum += 1) {

            tableSrces = tableArray[tableResEnum].src;

            //alert(tableSrcTapped);

            if (tableSrces === tableSrcTapped) {
                tableArray[tableResEnum].removeEventListener('click', tableUntap);
                tableArray[tableResEnum].addEventListener('click', tableTap);
                tableArray[tableResEnum].src = window.location + 'resources/tableBase.svg';
            } /*else if () {

            }*/
        }

        resTableArray.splice(0, resTableArray.length);
    }
```

Set/Unset a particular table:

```
    tableUntap = function () {
        $(this).unbind('click', tableUntap);
        $(this).bind('click', tableTap);
        this.setAttribute('src', 'resources/tableBase.svg');
        resTableArray.shift(this);
    };

    tableTap = function () {
        $(this).unbind('click', tableTap);
        $(this).bind('click', tableUntap);
        this.setAttribute('src', 'resources/tableTapped.svg');
        resTableArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
    };
```

Convert the elements within the 'eatPlace' class to an array:

```
        $('.eatPlace').bind('click', tableTap);

    tableList = document.getElementsByClassName('eatPlace');

    tableArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(tableList);
```

Table instantiation:

```
   for (tableEnum = 1; tableEnum <= tableNum; tableEnum += 1) {

        tableImg = document.createElement('IMG');
        tableImg.setAttribute('src', 'resources/tableBase.svg');
        tableImg.setAttribute('id', 'table' + tableEnum);
        tableImg.setAttribute('class', 'eatPlace');
        tableImg.setAttribute('width', '15%');
        tableImg.setAttribute('height', '15%');

        $('#tableBox').append(tableImg, tableEnum);

        if (tableEnum % 4 === 0) {
            $('#tableBox').append("\n");
        }

        if (tableEnum === tableNum) {
            $('#tableBox').append("<div id='subbles' class='ajaxButton'>Next</div>");
            $('#tableBox').append("<div id='cazzles' class='ajaxButton'>Cancel</div>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake is in tapping and untapping tables.

When you push a Table to your array, your pushing its ID.

```
resTableArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
```

It will add id's of elements, depending on the order of user clicking the tables.
While untapping its always removing the first table.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

```
resTableArray.shift(this);
```

So, when user clicks tables 1, 2, 3. And unclicks 3, the shift will remove table 1.

Lets fix this by removing untapped table

```
tableUntap = function () {
    $(this).unbind('click', tableUntap);
    $(this).bind('click', tableTap);
    this.setAttribute('src', 'http://imgur.com/a7J8OJ5.png');
    var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
    var elementIndex = resTableArray.indexOf(elementID);
    resTableArray.splice(elementIndex, 1);
};
```

So you were missing some tables after untapping.

Well lets fix tableClear,

You have a array with tapped tables, but you are searching in main array.

```
function tableClear() {

    tableLen = resTableArray.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < tableLen; i++) {
        var idString = "#" + resTableArray[i];

        var $element = $(idString);

        $element.unbind('click', tableUntap);
        $element.bind('click', tableTap);
        $element.attr("src", 'http://imgur.com/a7J8OJ5.png');

    }

    resTableArray = [];
}
```

Im searching only tapped tables, and then just untap them and remove handlers.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r9ewnxzs/

Your mistake was to wrongly remove at untapping elements.

Comment: THANKS! :D It seems so obvious to select elements from the array, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Sorry if my question was a bit terse and authoritarianish I don't think I was in the best state of mind when I wrote it.

Comment: All of your suggestions look good, I'll test them out and accept if they work. Thanks again :)

Comment: Personally I would encapsulate all logic of tapping tables into single JavaScript object, where I would keep references to html DOM, to be able to quickly update view of tables, while keeping all other neccessary data in object. After that, would keep whole logic as bunch of small objects.

Comment: So you'd assign tables a "tapped" boolean, then alter the DOM depending on the value of the boolean?

Comment: I would try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1fnrmu4c/2/ , a simple Object, which holds whole logic. Then would at creating Tables, just keep array of all tables and at clearTables, just call on every object switch off. You need to adapt this example more to your situation, but it gives the overall idea.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It could definitely save a lot of code and make the program more efficient. I'll consider it later on (once I've built menues, a working order handler, things like that).